# NameResolutionFailure with HTTP Post Request.

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing Android Application using Xamarin.  I have login screen with two EditText fields.

I need to write code for login request via a HTTP POST request.

I have this code:

```
 Button signin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
        var email = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.username);
        var password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.password);

        email_data = email.Text;
        password_data = password.Text;

        signin.Click += async delegate
        {


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Text))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Please, fill email", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Please, fill password", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var content = new StringContent(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { username = email_data, password = password_data }));
                var result = await client.PostAsync("http://stg-api.tieit.io/auth/login", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var tokenJson = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(tokenJson.ToString());
                }

                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(HomeView));
                StartActivity(intent);

            }
        };
```

But when I tap `signin` button, I have this error.

`System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure`

> Unhandled Exception: 10-05 12:06:26.877 E/mono    (27175):
>   System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure 10-05
>   12:06:26.877 E/mono-rt (27175): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure 10-05
>   12:06:26.889 I/IspDrv  (27175): {IspDrv} [~IspDrvImp]

How I can solve it?

Thank's for help

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the App? This error can occur if the App does not have rights to access the Internet.

Comment: you talk about `ACESS_NETWORKSTATE` and `Internet`? @auX

Comment: I check, they enabled @auX

Comment: what is your HttpClient Implementation Set to. Its in Android Options in properties, under Advanced? Fyi if user leaves Email blank and fills in the password, it will fall into the else statment and post.

Comment: Don't understood your question? @InitLipton

Comment: can you access that site via the device's (or emulator) browser?

Comment: What @InitLipton is saying that your code shown above will run the POST request if the password field is filled in by the user, then the `else` clause will run even if the email field is empty. IOW if first `if` fails, code goes to second `if` and if that fails, then the `else` block of code is run. This would not seem to be the desired flow. But that should be unrelated to the NameResolutionFailure which means that a DNS server could not resolve the host name to an IP Address or that there is no internet connection as noted already.

Answer (score 2):

I just did a `nslookup` for stg-api.tieit.io and no result was returned, however I get an IP for tieit.io. If the subdomain stg-api.tieit.io is on a private network, your code needs to run on a device on that same private network. If that sub-domain should be on the internet, then you need to create a DNS entry for stg-api.tieit.io to map it to an IP Address. Talk to your IT manager if you do not have control of the DNS entries for that domain.